# How to register all services under the crate "service" in Actix Web

Tags: rust, actix-web

I have a crate 'services' with all services for the App

Here's an example of one of the services, using the `#[get("/orders")]` macro for routing

```
#[get("/orders")]
pub async fn fetch_orders(state: Data<AppState>) -> impl Responder {
    let db: Addr<DbActor> = state.as_ref().db.clone();

    match db.send(FetchOrders).await {
        Ok(Ok(info)) => HttpResponse::Ok().json(info),
        Ok(Err(_)) => HttpResponse::NotFound().json("No orders found"),
        _ => HttpResponse::InternalServerError().json("Unable to retrieve orders"),
    }
}
```

Now, when creating the App, in `main.rs`, I explicitly register each service using `.service()`

```
use services::*;

App::new()
    .app_data(Data::new(AppState {
        db: db_addr.clone(),
    }))
    .service(fetch_orders::fetch_orders)
    .service(fetch_orders::fetch_single_order)
    .service(fetch_menu::fetch_menu)
```

The issue is I've been creating quite a few new services, and explicitly registering each one for the App seems nonsensical. Is there a way to just wrap everything under the `services` crate? or maybe a macro?

Answer (score 0):

You may see here the way they have done it, with `.configure` and `fn init`: https://github.com/SeaQL/sea-orm/blob/master/examples/actix_example/api/src/lib.rs#L186

Comment: Please actually provide the answer with code example inside the answer, because URLs change.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a number of ways. Probably the most straight-forward is to use scope:

```
use services::*;

App::new()
    .app_data(Data::new(AppState {
        db: db_addr.clone(),
    })).service(
       ::actix::web::scope("/services")
           .service(fetch_orders::fetch_orders)
           .service(fetch_orders::fetch_single_order)
           .service(fetch_menu::fetch_menu)
    )
```

this will mount all of the end-points under "/services"

Comment: I think OP is more concerned about getting rid of all the explicit `.service` calls. Like having one macro or function `.services(services)` that loads every endpoint defined in the `services` module. AFAIK, this does not exist